# BackgroundTask returns null Why? It should return the string specified in try block

Tags: android, android-studio

BackgroundTask returns null.Why? It should return the string specified in try block.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void...Voids)
    {


            try {

                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream ip = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ip));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((json_string = bufferedreader.readLine())!= null)
                {
                    sb.append(json_string + "\n");
                }
                bufferedreader.close();
                ip.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return sb.toString().trim();

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }



                        return null;
    }
```

Comment: please post Logcat??

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` in `try` block wasn't reached, probably any exception occurred and was catch. Check your `logcat` and find your problem.